# Is there way to only open the mobile keyboard when using inputfields in unity3d on the OnMouseUp() method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I want to know if there is a way to only open the keyboard after the click OnMouseUp() not on the  OnMouseDown() method. I have tried to modify the inputfield.cs script but it does not open.

[here is the video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQI4oLp-D7w)

Comment: This is possible. It's important to show what you've tried so that you won't get the-same or similar answer.

Comment: the only thing I have tried is to change the script but that did not work for me and I'm not too experienced to come up with a more clever plan

Comment: I did something similar in the past. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but tricky and complicated especially when new to Unity.

Do the following:

**1**. *From the Editor* disable [`interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) on the InputFields you want to only open keyboard when key is released. On the *"Disabled Color"* of the InputField, make sure to change that to white and the alpha to full (255) so that the InputField will not look like it is disabled.

[image]

---

You don't have to do the remaining steps below because it's already done in the script at the end of this post but the steps below shows you how this is done.

**2**. When the `InputField` interactable is disabled, it cannot accept clicks anymore. Clicking on it will **not** open the keyboard.

You now have to use [`GraphicRaycaster.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) to do a manual UI raycast. The result will be stored in a `List` of [`RaycastResult`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.RaycastResult.html).

**3**. Since you want to open the keyboard only when the click or touch is released, put the [`GraphicRaycaster.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) inside `if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))` for desktop devices and `if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)` for mobile devices. They will both return `true` on the frame when click or touch is released.

**4**. When the click is released with the example in **#3**, check if `InputField` is in the `List` of the `RaycastResult` with `result.GetComponentInParent<InputField>()`, if it is an `InputField`, manually select the `InputField` with the `SetSelectedGameObject` and `OnPointerClick` functions. After this, the keyboard should open on the `InputField` and that's when the key is released not when pressed.

After this, register to the [`onEndEdit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onEndEdit.html) event on the `InputField`.

**5**. When the `onEndEdit` event is called, de-select the `InputField` with the `DeactivateInputField` function, un-register from the `onEndEdit` event with the `RemoveAllListeners` function then disable or set interactable back to `false`.

---

Do step **#1** only for all the `InputField` you want to only open keyboard when click or touch is released then, create a script named "`ReleaseInputOpenKeyboard`", copy the script below into it then attach it to an empty GameObject in the scene. The mobile-keyboards will only show on the `InputField` when the click or touch is released instead of when it is pressed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ReleaseInputOpenKeyboard: MonoBehaviour
{
    GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;
    EventSystem m_EventSystem;

    List<GameObject> inputFieldProcessedThisFrame = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        m_Raycaster = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
        //Fetch the Event System from the Scene
        m_EventSystem = FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_EDITOR
        //DESKTOP COMPUTERS
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            SelectInputField();
        }
#else
        if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended))
        {
            SelectInputField();
        }
#endif
    }

    void SelectInputField()
    {
        //Set up the new Pointer Event
        PointerEventData m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem);
        //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the mouse position
        m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        //Create a list of Raycast Results
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
        m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);

        //For every result returned, output the name of the GameObject on the Canvas hit by the Ray
        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            InputField ipf = result.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<InputField>();
            //Check if object hit is an InputField and make sure we have not processed this object this frame
            if (ipf && !inputFieldProcessedThisFrame.Contains(ipf.gameObject))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit " + ipf.gameObject.name);

                //Mark this InputField as processed
                inputFieldProcessedThisFrame.Add(ipf.gameObject);

                //Enable interactable
                ipf.interactable = true;

                //Focus on the InputField
                ActivateInputField(ipf, m_EventSystem);

                //Add event to detect when the Input is deselected
                ipf.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate { OnInputEnd(ipf); });
            }
        }

        //Reset processed InputField
        if (inputFieldProcessedThisFrame.Count > 0)
            inputFieldProcessedThisFrame.Clear();
    }

    void ActivateInputField(InputField ipf, EventSystem evSys)
    {
        evSys.SetSelectedGameObject(ipf.gameObject, new BaseEventData(evSys));
        ipf.OnPointerClick(new PointerEventData(evSys));
    }


    //Detects when InputField is deselected then disable interactible
    void OnInputEnd(InputField ipf)
    {
        StartCoroutine(OnInputEndCOR(ipf));
    }

    IEnumerator OnInputEndCOR(InputField ipf)
    {
        //Disable interactable then remove event
        ipf.DeactivateInputField();
        ipf.onEndEdit.RemoveAllListeners();

        /*Wait until EventSystem is no longer in selecting mode
         This prevents the "Attempting to select while already selecting an object" error
         */
        while (EventSystem.current.alreadySelecting)
            yield return null;

        ipf.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check it ?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! It definitely worked! The problem I am having now is that it won't let me move the canvas. I posted a video that I linked in the question to explain the issue a little bit more! thank you again

Comment: I saw the video. 1.Did this issue start after you followed my instruction? 2.Are you using scroll view or scrollbar?  I need to know how you were originally moving the object

Comment: HEY, I don't know how many times I'm going to say thank you!  and it did not start  after what you told me to do (it kind of sounds like that on my last comment, my bad) I am using scroll view and the way I am able to move it right now is by clicking on top of the toggles and then sliding my finger. If I click on top of the InputFields it does not let me. I always figured it was because it opened the keyboard right away but after you fixed that issue for me (thank you) I know that's not the case.

Comment: You're welcome. Your scroll view is likely messed up. I just replicated this on my with and made few InputFields into Scrollview and it worked fine. I was able to drag it. **1.** Make sure to have EventSystem in your scene. Go to *GameObject* --> *UI*  --> *Event System* to create a new one. **2.** If that's not the problem then there is a problem with your scroll view. Your InputFields must be the child of the "Content" object of the scroll view. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/9fNw2aq.png) image for the Hierarchy.

Comment: If that doesn't solve your issue, **delete** your current Scroll View. Create new Scroll View by going to *GameObject* --> *UI*  --> *Scroll View*. You can then put your InputField stuff under the "Content" object of the Scroll View. It should work because it works for me. You should be able to drag the objects under the "Content" object  around.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the check-mark if it solved your onmouseup issue. You can read more about why to accept answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: @unitydeveloper yes you just did! You know you did when you +2 on your reputation. And also the checkmark on this answer is now green.

Comment: I really appreciate you Programmer